# react-multi-carousel looking to give a free-scroll ability for carousel elements (targeting mobile)

Tags: reactjs, react-multi-carousel

I've been requested to give the react-multi-carousel component a free scroll ability for mobile using react-multi-carousel.
So when a user swipes (L or R) on mobile, the default scrolls to the next carousel item.
The default seems to lock that next carousel item to the left border of carousel-wrapper

The ask is to create a fluid scroll that doesn't lock into any carousel. So if a mobile user scrolls with intention, the carousel could very well scroll to the end of carousel items.

I assume the ability to achieve this lies somewhere in the slidesToSlide: num configuration but can't seem to get working.

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-multi-carousel-demo-forked-5th2b?file=/src/simple.js